# recommend a server side technology for gwt (beginner)

Tags: gwt

I am developing a gwt project and am looking for an appropriate server side technology.

it should support be open source and support user login (and not using openID...) with password recovery etc

it seems that the de-facto standard would be spring + hibernate. however, I am unfamiliar with neither of them and understand that the learning curve (especially for spring) is very high. gwt was quite easy to learn using GOOG's excellent online tutorials but the spring equivalent seem to impose lots of configuration files and deeper understanding of its internals.

so I am looking for a simpler server side technology to deploy my gwt app. I am definitely prepared to learn a new framework if necessary but not something that would take me 2 months just to understand the fundamentals...

any ideas...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) should get you started with a **GWT** app in no time. It even has scaffoling (like Rails) for easily generating code for views and models. Here is a good [video](http://s3.springsource.com/MRKT/roo/2010-01-Five_Minutes_Roo.mov) that introduces Roo and here is a [guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html#intro-first-steps) for the mandentory *10 minutes application* that Rails pioneered years ago.

Also a cool thing about Roo is that it gets you started quickly while still doing everything correctly (i.e. integrate with Spring security, Hibernate, Maven, ...).

**Edit**: You could also try [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com) (tutorial [here](http://vaadin.com/tutorial)) although I am unsure if that may be to simplistic for your needs.

Comment: thanks. Roo does seem very easy to start with, but I fear those inevitable cases where I would need to change the default setup and then run immediately into the black holes of AspectJ *which I don't know..), Hibernate (which I don't know) and the core spring stuff. no free lunches...

Comment: Spring is a very complicated world and Roo does help ease you into it although it does not hide it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Google AppEngine + GWT. It provides you a full development environment:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html

This post also provides some information on how to get started with Google Plugin for Eclipse, which supports GWT, Google AppEngine, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I second using Google App Engine, especially the Java version as it integrates so easily with GWT.  I am using it in this way right now.  App Engine has well written and complete docs, similar to those of GWT.

A simple way to integrate the build processes is to (1) use the GWT code generator to generate the standard project tree and ant build process and then (2) read this article on integrating GAE/Java with GWT:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine